# Очистка дублей и соединение

Tags: php

Добрый день или вечер )
У меня такая ситуация - скрин - http://joxi.ru/4Ak3jdEcynE9BA
Вообщем история.

Дали товар в csv и он дублируется но отличие в нем только в Options скажем разные цвета и мне нужно было удалить дубли и собрать  Options в товар (с новой строки PHP_EOL)

Сделал уже все кроме того что-бы собрать несколько этих опций в один товар. 
Подскажите пожалуйста

```
$handle = fopen("in1.csv", "r");
    $row = 1;
    $tovar = array();
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        foreach($data as $a_product) {
            $tovar['_ID_'] =  $data[0];
            $tovar['_NAME_'] =  $data[1];
            $tovar['_EAN_'] =  $data[2];
            $tovar['_CATEGORY_'] =  $data[3];
            $tovar['_MANUFACTURER_'] =  $data[5];
            $tovar['_ATTRIBUTES_'] =  "Характеристики"."|"."Количество цветов"."|".$data[6]."\r\n"."Характеристики"."|"."Стиль рисунка"."|".$data[7]."\r\n"."Характеристики"."|"."Ткань"."|".$data[8]
                ."\r\n"."Характеристики"."|"."Основной цвет"."|".$data[13]."\r\n"."Характеристики"."|"."Материал"."|".$data[22]."\r\n"."Характеристики"."|"."Cтрана изготовитель"."|".$data[24]
                ."\r\n"."Характеристики"."|"."Плотность"."|".$data[25]
                ."\r\n".$data[16]."|".$data[15]."|".$data[25];
            $tovar['_OPTIONS_'] = "Пока еще пусто";
            $tovar['_IMAGE_'] = $data[23];
        }
        $articles[] = $tovar;
        $result = $articles;
        $keys=array(); // Массив ключей, которые уже встречались
        foreach($result as $k=>$val) {
            if(array_key_exists($val['_ID_'],$keys)) {
                unset($result[$k]['_NAME_']);
                unset($result[$k]['_EAN_']);
                unset($result[$k]['_CATEGORY_']);
                unset($result[$k]['_MANUFACTURER_']);
                unset($result[$k]['_ATTRIBUTES_']);
                unset($result[$k]['_IMAGE_']);
            } else {
                $keys[$val['_ID_']]=1;

            }
        }
        $row++;
    }
```

Comment: Историю прочитал, а вопрос то в чём заключается? :)

Comment: http://joxi.ru/12M1vXxTMQbJe2
Мне нужно последующие опции прикрепить к первой

Comment: @AndryLomakin не понятен все равно смысл вопроса. В нижнем цикле (там где много UNSET) вы эти дубликаты и обрабатываете (удаляете их части). Если вам надо чтобы 2 и 3 было как 1, то удалите этот цикл.

Comment: @Manitikyl Мне надо что-бы с 2 и 3 эта Опция добавилась в 1

Comment: Ничего не понял. Если получится внятно описать задание, удалите этот вопрос и создайте новый понятный. Не можете сформулировать, помочь вам тоже никто не сможет.